# How to add constant inside Joi validator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, joi

I have a joi validator code:

```
city: Joi.string().valid([cities]).required()
```

and constant

```
const cities = require("../cities");
```

I want to add cities inside city joi validator. Because when I test city. only specific city values must be inside of the city.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Did you take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking? Please add more infos about your problem and be sure that your [example](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is complete and verifiable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.valid`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.6.0/API.md#anyvalidvalue---aliases-only-equal) can take an array as an argument. As your `cities.js` exports an array of objects, you can first extract the `value` from array of object and validate against those.

```
const cities = require("../cities"); // cities is an array.

const cityValues = cities.map(aCity => aCity.value); // extract the value


city: Joi.string().valid(cityValues).required() // pass the array
```

Comment: message": "child \"cities\" fails because [\"cities\" must be one of [[object Object], [object Object], [object Object], It gives this error. But path is correct why it gives empty array object

Comment: Can you post `cities.js` code? It seems exported array it is an array of objects.

Comment: const cities = [
  { text: "Gondor", value: "gondor", id: 1 },
  { text: "Mordor", value: "mordor", id: 2 }]

Comment: Okay, I assume that the `value` field of the `<option>` element is set to `city.value` and not to `city.name`

Comment: After that I need to do when gondor is selected, I will give restriction for the subcities. If gondor is selected gondor ={ gondor's subcities} if other is choosen the other subcities are valid.

Comment: Please check the answer!

Comment: Again, please check the answer. Update your code required. You are using `...cities.value` which is wrong.

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer! That would help me a lot :)